# How to track one domain from two google analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We got one domain that has data for different client. What we wanna do is have a separate Google Analytics profile under one account to track traffic data for each of their pages.
In other word, in google analytics code can we have two Account id ? So both accounts can get see the tracking data for specific pages.

I think I have not made myself clear yet. let me try again..

There is one domain abc.com with several pages. For example abc.com/xvy belongs to userA and abc.com/kju belongs to userB. We have one google Analytics account that is tracking everything on abc.com. What I want to do is have another profile or new google analytics account to track all the data belongs to userA and userB separately. I do have an option to put different tracking code on pages that belongs to different users.

For example, pages belongs to userA can have diferent tracking from pages belong to userB.
But at the same time I want to track all the pages under one account as well...

Is there anyway I can achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

You should [set up a separate profile](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009714) for each area of the site you want tracked separately. Profiles all belong to the same account, so you will be able to see all of your data with a single sign-in.

Keep the same tracking code on all areas of the site, but just [apply filters](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034380) to the different profiles.

To follow your example, I would set up Profile A and Profile B. You could keep a Whole Site profile to collect all of the data, too, if that is useful to you. For Profile A, apply a Request URI filter for ^/xvy and for Profile B, apply a Request URI filter for ^/kju. I'm assuming here that the different areas of the site are defined by the first subdirectory, so you may have to adjust those filter suggestions if the structure of the site is different.

Comment: I think you have explained it but can you elaborate on "apply URI filter..." the problem is I do not know what code will generate after the first "/" in the url. There is no sequence no order its just unique and random. For now I am using segments. As those pages are generated from an API.

Comment: Yeah, profiles are not going to work well for this case. Profiles have to be made by hand, and you'd have to know the URI (the part after the first "/" in the URL) as soon as possible to create a filter. Advanced segments are your best bet for dynamically generated things like what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Soon we are gonna change URL structure that will help with this matter. Thanks for taking time to look into this.